# Is there is a more efficent way to remove duplicate integers

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I was writing a function to remove duplicate integers in a list, but I don't think I did it the most efficient way possible. Any suggestions?

```
def remove_dups(items):
    new_list = sorted(items)
    i_postion = 0
    if len(new_list) > 1:
        for i in new_list:
            counter = 1
            while counter < len(new_list):
                if i_postion + counter < len(new_list):
                    if new_list[i_postion] == new_list[i_postion + counter]:
                        new_list.remove(new_list[i_postion + counter])
                counter += 1
            i_postion += 1

        #A check if the list is only one number multiple times
        if new_list[0] == new_list[1]:
            new_list.remove(new_list[1])
    else:
        return(new_list)

    return(new_list)
```

Comment: `return list(set(items))` would be a lot simpler..

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the order and all elements of list `L` are immutable, use a set:

```
L = [3, 4, 5, 4, 2, 3, 5]
>>> res = list(set(L))
```

If you need to preserve order:

```
res = []
seen = set()
for ele in L:
    if ele in seen:
        continue
    res.append(ele)
    seen.add(ele)

>>> res
[3, 4, 5, 2]
```